# Issue deploying flow templates as Inactive in Package when there is a Subflow

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, automation, isv

I have a Managed Package with two Flow Templates.  FTParent is a parent flow template, and the other (we will call it FTsub) is also a flow template.  Initially, they were both packaged as Active, and I want to deactivate them and deploy new versions to client orgs that are Inactive by default.

Initially, I changed the status on both FTParent, and FTSub as Draft (shown as Inactive), deployed to packaging org, and deactivated old versions of FTParent and FTSub.   Uploading a new version of the package fails with the following:

Error Details: FlowDefinition - FTParent
Problem: The referenced flow FTSub has no active version. Ensure it has an active version before you activate the flow FTParent.

I then took steps and left an active version of FTSub, and the package did upload successfully.  I took another step and deactivated FTSub, but again the package upload failed.

Is there any way to deactivate both the Flow templates when they are referenced as parent and subflow in a managed package?  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is this for a classic or 2GP managed package?